# Outlook IMAP Local Messages vs Server Messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

When adding an IMAP (not Exchange) account to Outlook (2016) that connects to our local IMAP server, the user is presented with an option "mail to keep offline" slider, with various intervals going up to "forever". I assumed this just meant that Outlook will keep copies of the messages local going back to whatever the slider is set at, however after investigating the search function and folders on the left column obey this setting. I assumed IMAP meant all your email messages are stored on the server and no need to have everything local taking up HD space (and huge .ost files).

Is there a setting in Outlook to store *all* my messages on the server only, and also have search work on messages on the server without having to download copies of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Online mode is only an option for Exchange email account in Outlook desktop client. For IMAP account, it is by design that it would cache emails on your web server to local datafile and we cannot change this behavior.

For your needs, seems using web mail is a more suitable workaround. Or, would you mind trying Exchange email account?

Comment: I wish I could, however these users only have an old IMAP server available.  Thanks.